# In SQL, can you nest a SELECT statement in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

In SQL is it possible to nest a SELECT statement in the VALUES clause of the INSERT statement?  I'm using MySQL and would like to query the table for the max value of a field plus one when creating a new record, as shown below.

```
INSERT into attornies (
  LawOfficeId, LawOfficeName
) VALUES (
  (select max(LawOfficeID)+1 from attornies), 
  'Wee, Sue Em and Howe'
);
```

I'm not sure if my syntax is bad, what I'm trying to do is not possible, etc.  Of course, If I try this as two separate statements it works but I would like to make it one statement.  I know one suggestion is to use auto increment but I don't want to.

If this question has already been answered please point me in that direction.  If not .... Help.

Comment: It's not neccesairy to do it that way. Just do the `insert ... select` with the MAX, and add your hardcoded value next to the MAX.

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do it

```
INSERT into attornies (
  LawOfficeId, LawOfficeName
)
select max(LawOfficeID) + 1,'Wee, Sue Em and Howe' from attornies;
```

However this is not recommended over auto increment since you are likely going to run into duplicate primary key situation if multiple threads are doing the insert

Comment: I am on the assumption with this column flagged as a primary key all but one (or all) inserts would fail as duplicate keys.  My concern here is that if I have to restore the database from an export it is going to create different values for LawOfficeId (really bad) or the import will cause problems for auto increment.  Is this something I don't have to worry about?

Comment: @BarryS.Rayfield export and import will not change the value. If it does then better switch to another DB. flagging it as a primary key + auto increment will never cause duplicate key insert unless DB screws up or you did something dumb like reseeding it back to lower value. That's the whole purpose of it.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should work.  Scalar subqueries are allowed in the `values` clause of the `insert`.

In general, it would more commonly be written as:

```
insert into attornies (LawOfficeId, LawOfficeName) 
   select max(LawOfficeID)+1,  'Wee, Sue Em and Howe'
   from attornies;
```

However, this is not the right way to do what you seem to want.  Instead, create `attornies` -- which I am renaming to `lawOffices` because that seems to be the intention -- with an auto-increment column:

```
create table lawOffices (
    lawOfficeId int auto_increment primary key,
    lawOfficeName varchar(255)
);
```

And then do:

```
insert into lawOffices (lawOfficeName)
    values ( 'Wee, Sue Em and Howe' );
```

The database does the work of incrementing the id.

Comment: It seems the "should" is a "won't". 
 When I tried his statement on rextester it failed on MySql with the interesting error `You can't specify target table 'attornies' for update in FROM clause`. But it's fine with a `(select 1)` in the values.

Comment: That's called a Mutating Table Problem.  You can't do a select against the same table you are updating.  Other DB products have "less" issue with this than MySQL.

Comment: @LukStorms . . . Very amusing.  I almost never use `values` with `insert` anyways, so I never noticed this in MySQL.

Comment: I understand the insistence to use the auto-increment flag for the LawOfficeId column.  However, my experience with auto-increment comes from what you would call the bad old days of auto-increment.  In other words, if I have to restore/import the table from an export that is not in LawOfficeId order I run the risk of either MySQL changing the value of LawOfficeId or causing problems for auto-increment selecting it’s next value.  By keeping it independent of auto-increment I avoid this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the syntax you show.

```
mysql> INSERT into attornies (
    ->   LawOfficeId, LawOfficeName
    -> ) VALUES (
    ->   (select max(LawOfficeID)+1 from attornies), 
    ->   'Wee, Sue Em and Howe'
    -> );
ERROR 1093 (HY000): You can't specify target table 'attornies' for update in FROM clause
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subquery-errors.html says:

> You can use a subquery for assignment within an UPDATE statement because subqueries are legal in UPDATE and DELETE statements as well as in SELECT statements. However, you cannot use the same table (in this case, table t1) for both the subquery FROM clause and the update target.

The doc is talking about using a subquery in an UPDATE statement, but the same rule applies in an INSERT or DELETE statement.

However, this works:

```
mysql> INSERT into attornies (
    ->   LawOfficeId, LawOfficeName
    -> )
    -> select max(LawOfficeID) + 1,'Wee, Sue Em and Howe' from attornies;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html says:

> The target table of the INSERT statement may appear in the FROM clause of the SELECT part of the query. However, you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery.
>
> When selecting from and inserting into the same table, MySQL creates an internal temporary table to hold the rows from the SELECT and then inserts those rows into the target table.

I agree with the other answers and comments who warn you against using the `MAX()+1` method of getting the next id value. This method is susceptible to race conditions. Use an auto-increment column instead.

Comment: I stated this comment in a couple of places but this is a big concern of mine.  I understand the insistence to use the auto-increment flag for the LawOfficeId column. However, my experience with auto-increment comes from what you would call the bad old days of auto-increment. In other words, if I have to restore/import the table from an export that is not in LawOfficeId order I run the risk of either MySQL changing the value of LawOfficeId or causing problems for auto-increment selecting it’s next value. By keeping it independent of auto-increment I avoid this problem.

Comment: MySQL does not generate a new auto-increment value if your INSERT specifies a value for the auto-increment column. That is, giving a value overrides the auto-increment behavior, and it takes the value you give. That's how MySQL dump and restore works — the dump includes the current values even for auto-increment columns, so those are the values restored when you re-import the dump.

Comment: I can understand if your experience has been with some other databases (like Oracle) that use triggers to call a SEQUENCE object and replace the id column with sequence-generated values, that would have the opposite behavior, and generate new values during import even if your dump file included values.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, you've all convinced me.  In addition, I did a bit of testing of import/export with an auto-increment field in MySQL.  My concerns are no longer justified.  I'll discard my max()+1 idea as unnecessary and go with auto-increment.

I would also like to thank Steve, Bill Karwin and Gordon Linoff for correcting my SQL and pointing me in the proper direction if I had continued with my original idea.